# Updating MonoDevelop to 5.9.6

Tags: release-freya, pantheon-terminal

I was having allot of difficulty trying to update the version of MonoDevelop that is available for elementary OS Freya. I was trying to run these commands to get it done:

```
 sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
 echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
 sudo apt-get update
```

For some reason the `sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list` command would not copy the `echo` line into the `mono-xamarin.list` file even though I was using the `sudo` command. So five hours later and hundreds of searches on Google, it finally hit me to try to just add the line by copying and pasting it directly into the file. Of course I had to open my file manager as root in order to do this. After long hours figuring this out I finally got my MonoDevelop updated to the latest one.

Why did the `sudo tee` command not work to copy the `echo` line into the `mono-xamarin.list` file?